# Mapping a read-only property with no setter using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a domain class that looks like this. I want NHibernate to *save* the current value of `LastUpdate` when inserting/updating so that I can use it in queries, but to ignore it when retrieving a `Foo` from the database and let the object itself recalculate the value when I actually access it.

```
public class Foo {
    public DateTime LastUpdate {
        get {
            /* Complex logic to determine last update by inspecting History */
            return value;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<History> History { get; set; }
    /* etc. */
}
```

My mapping for `Foo` looks like this:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> {
    Map(x => x.LastUpdate)
        .ReadOnly();
    HasMany(x => x.History);
    // etc...
}
```

I thought that `ReadOnly()` was what I wanted to accomplish this, but when I try to create a SessionFactory I get the following exception:

> Error: FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
>   ---> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property 'LastUpdate' in class 'Foo'.

The property doesn't have a setter because *it shouldn't be set, only read from*. Is `ReadOnly()` the correct thing to do here? If not, what?

(NHibernate v3.0b1, Fluent NHibernate v1.1)

Comment: The ReadOnly(); only sets in the generated mapping xml streams the insert="false" and the update="false" attributes of the LastUpdate property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ReadOnly` instructs Fluent NHibernate to not look for changes on this property, this does not equate to a read-only property in compiler-world. Your property isn't read-only in NHibernate's eyes because you're expecting it to be populated from your database. What you need to do is tell NHibernate that it should access the value of that property through a private field with the same name (lowercased) as the property.

```
Map(x => x.LastUpdate)
  .Access.Field();
```

There are several alternatives to using `Field`, which one you use will depend on how you name your private fields.

Comment: I don't actually want the property to be populated from the database, it is calculated dynamically in the getter. I just want it to be saved to the database so that I can query against it.

Comment: If Nhibernate does not populate it, it will not know to save it because it has no idea if and when the value changes.  Both solutions offered are exactly the same and do what you described.  NHibernate can access the variable by field so you don't need a setter.  When you access the getter the value will be calculated dynamically.  When you update NHibernate will save the value.  The fact that NHibernate populates it from the db should be irrelevant - until you access you don't know/care, when you do access it the value will be calculated.  Look at as "initialized" by Nhibernate if it helps.

Comment: @Sisyphus That explanation helps a lot. Thank you.

Comment: This would be access="field" for mapping XML, just in case someone is looking for that.

Comment: I would use Access.ReadOnly()

Comment: Same effect but `Access.ReadOnly()` is more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

As far as NHibernate goes, you can map to a field, i.e member variable so Nhibernate can access the member variable directly.  So you can create a member variable like _lastUpdate that can be mapped directly.  Nhibernate will now have a variable to use and you can control the value separately in your getter because NHibernate will no longer use the property getter.  It will save the value, and retrieve it too, but the retrieved value should not matter because as soon as you access through your getter you can recalculate it.  Ditto for private variables with no getters or setters.

In a regular hbm you would just map access=field.  Everyone does it.  Apparently Fluent is not a simple.  I don't use Fluent  ...

EDIT ...

find whatever the seemingly always moving target for mapping private backing fields is in your version and use that ...

Comment: It is as simple in Fluent NHibernate: `Map(x => x.LastUpdate).Access.Field()`

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty private setter to your class:

```
        private set { }
```

I also add an attribute and a comment to document my intent (and make ReSharper happy):

```
        [UsedImplicitly]
        // ReSharper disable once ValueParameterNotUsed
        private set { }
```